# Abstract types in R

Tags: r, julia, r-s4, abstract-data-type

I want to create class in R, let's say it is an S4 class for a person. E.g.

```
setClass("Person", slots = list(name = "character", mood = "myMoodType"))
```

Now I want to create `myMoodType` to be an abstract type that can only take the three values "Happy", "Sad" and "Unknown".

I know that I could do this using the validity for S4 classes and have the mood as a character type and check the validity by verifying that the character string provided is one of the three options I list. But I would like to know if I can define an abstract type, like in julia, e.g.

```
abstract myMoodType
type Happy   <: myMoodType             end
type Sad     <: myMoodType             end
type Unknown <: myMoodType             end
```

What would be the correct way to approach this in R?

Comment: In my opinion a better solution for both languages, is to declare `myMoodType` as an  `Enum`, with 3 values of Happy ,Sad and Unknown

Comment: Are you wedded to S4? It’s not a very well thought out mechanism for OOP in general — I suggest using either S3 or R6 instead, and to forget that S4 ever existed. That said, neither S3 nor R6 will really help you here, and indeed most OOP implementations in most languages do not support what you want to achieve well (which is known as [sum types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union)).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I just picked S4 as an example.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for clarifying this for me, I guess I am looking into R6 now, but I think that for the purpose of what I am doing I will not need a sum type. I realize that what I was asking for may have been too general for what I really need.

Comment: Consider whether you really want a possible level named "Unknown" since R already uses `NA` for marking missing information.

Comment: @Backlin … and `NULL`, and `NaN`, and `NA_character_`, and `NA_real_`, and … ;-)

Comment: Great, thanks guys :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might not be one of R's strongest and most smooth feature, but you could solve it in the following way. For more information see [the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/setClass.html) or the [Advanced R chapter on S4](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html).

First set up the Person class with the mood represented as a factor, and link it to a validation function that checks its levels.

```
check_person <- function(object) {
    if(identical(levels(object@mood), c("Happy", "Sad", "Unknown"))){
        return(TRUE)
    } else {
        return("Invalid mood.")
    }
}

setClass("Person",
         representation(name = "character", mood = "factor"),
         prototype = list(name = NA_character_,
                          mood = factor(NA, c("Happy", "Sad", "Unknown"))),
         validity = check_person)
```

Creating new instances with `new` is however a bit messy since we have to write out all the levels each time:

```
john <- new("Person", name="John", mood=factor("Happy", levels=c("Happy", "Sad", "Unknown")))
lucy <- new("Person", name="Lucy", mood=factor("Sad", levels=c("Happy", "Sad", "Unknown")))
```

Otherwise we'll get an error:

```
new("Person", name="Eve", mood="Unknown")
```

```
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “Person” object: invalid object for slot "mood" in class "Person":
  got class "character", should be or extend class "factor"
```

To get around that you could make your own constructor:

```
new_person <- function(name, mood){
    new("Person", name = name, mood = factor(mood, levels = c("Happy", "Sad", "Unknown")))
}
new_person("Eve", "Unknown")
```

```
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] "Eve"

Slot "mood":
[1] Unknown
Levels: Happy Sad Unknown
```

Comment: I think OP said explicitly that this is not the solution they want, and they want the “mood” to be of a specific class type from within the set of a sum type.

Comment: @KonradRudolph this answer covers the functionality that I want. Maybe I should edit my question in that regard.

Comment: @Gumeo Eh, if this answer is what you’re after just mark it as accepted. That’s sufficient I think.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You're right, my solution does not meet the OP's request, but I thought it would be the way to go in R to get the desired functionality.